# Deduced distribution of X from X^2

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

If I have a random variable $X^{2}$ with distribution $X^{2}∼Γ(α,β)$ then what would be the distribution of  $Y=X$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: As stated, there are multiple solutions. Is $X$ restricted to non-negative values? Edit the answer into your question.

Comment: please , if we can explain more, i don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our challenge is to deduce the distribution of $X$ from that of $X^2$. If $X$ is a non-negative variable, $$P(Y\le y)=P(X^2\le y^2)=\int_0^{y^2}f(t) dt,\,f(t):=\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)}t^{\alpha-1}\exp -\beta t.$$For $y\ge 0$< the pdf of $Y$ is then$$p(y)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0 & y<0\\
\frac{d}{dy}\int_{0}^{y^{2}}f(t)dt=2\frac{\beta^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}y^{2\alpha-1}\exp-\beta y^{2} & y\ge0
\end{array}\right..$$But other solutions exist. What happens if $X$ is a non-positive variable instead? Then the pdf of $Y$ is $p(-y)$. Or what if $X$ has an even distribution? Then the pdf of $Y$ is $(p(y)+p(-y))/2$. In fact, for any $q\in [0,\,1]$ we can take the pdf of $Y$ as $qp(y)+(1-q)p(-y)$.

Comment: From your answer, i understand that the distribution of $X$ is not a usual distribution, thank you